# What are the advantages of using REST APIs directly over API wrappers?

Tags: rest, api, wrapper

When should I choose one over the other?

The way I see it API wrappers are so much simpler to use but I feel like there's something I'm not seeing, so can you enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

REST is a software design to decouple clients from APIs though it is often misunderstood as simple URI design thingy due to the fact that it is often based on HTTP.

Advantages of using APIs and clients that support REST is clearly, that clients are not coupled to any API in particular and are therefore tolerant to changes done on the server side like moving resources to different endpoints. Like a browser is able to present content of a sheer infinite number of web pages, true RESTful clients should behave identical and be able to communicate with any API that supports REST. It may learn on the fly how to deal with new content type by looking up some processing routines dynamically (similar to plugins of certain applications) or fallback to a default handling (reporting errors or presenting unknown data as plain text).

An API wrapper is often used to create clients that are limited to a certain API only. This simplifies development as the client can contain certain logic needed for interaction with the API like en/de-coding messages sent to or received from the service, list all available operations and similar stuff. Often URI endpoints are also either injected through properties or hardcoded into the application. Also, the content type is often limited to XML or JSON and the rules on how to treat responses are hardcoded into the client directly. All these steps however tightly couple the client to the API. In case the API changes (or is enriched by further endpoints) the API wrapper has to be updated and shipped to each consumer otherwise users either won't be able to use the API or make use of the latest features.

API wrapper are often tailor made for the usage of the API and are also often much simpler to implement. They, however, also require constant updating in cases the API itself is changing as the wrapper is incapable of handling these changes itself. REST clients on the other hand are far more complicate to develop as the client somehow has to know (or learn) the semantical meaning of a certain response and has to infer somehow how to act upon received responses. Some parts of it are yet an active field of research (at least in automated processing).

As you asked on when to use which: In cases where you have to create an all-purpose client, a REST client is for sure the right thing to do. However, identifying the correct semantical treatment will be the true chanllenge for these clients IMO. In cases where you only need to provide a client frontend for customers (or users) and not much change is expected on the API itself, a wrapper may be much easier to implement. However, please don't call such a client RESTful!